# Work around for DO block not returning data

Tags: sql, postgresql, libpqxx

I'm writing a c++ postgres app using libpqxx. I have a postgres function that takes multiple text[] arrays as input parameters.  Since I cannot find a way in libpqxx to pass in arrays to a function (any help here welcome!), I am instead using a "DO" block and building the arrays directly in the DO sql before calling the function.  My problem is that the function inserts a row, and I need the id of the new row returned, but it seems like you can't return anything from a DO block.  Is this true, and if so, any ideas?  I really would like to get the id back within the transaction with the function call, but I don't see how I can do this.  Any tips/help appreciated.

Comment: 1) Have you looked at  [libpgxx insert array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73510086/libpqxx-array-data-with-prepared-statements)? 2) It is true you can't return anything from `DO` per [DO starement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html). 3) If you stick with `DO` the only solution I can think of at the moment is to write the returned `id` to some table and then fetch from there.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I had found the exact link you mention (on inserting array), which is how I wanted to do it (and is really the correct way), but I could not get it to work (I was getting compiler errors deep inside libpqxx).  Thus the DO "solution".

Comment: I am not a c++/libpgxx user so I am not going to be of much help there. The best I can do is point you at [libpqxx issues](https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx/issues). Maybe raising an issue with compiler errors will get you a response/answer.